# I18n translation with i18n-active_record: same form for same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-i18n

I am working on an app in Rails 4 using i18n-active_record 0.1.0 to keep my translations in the database rather than in a .yml-file. It works fine.

One thing that I am struggling with, however, is that each translation record is one record per locale, i.e.

```
#1. { locale: "en", key: "hello", value: "hello")
#2. { locale: "se", key: "hello", value: "hej")
```

which makes updating them a tedious effort. I would like instead to have it as one, i.e.:

```
{ key: "hello", value_en: "hello", value_se: "hej" }
```

or similar in order to update all instances of one key in one form. I can't seem to find anything about that, which puzzles me.

Is there any way to easily do this? Any type of hacks would be ok as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own Translation functionality using Globalize. It does not explicitly rely on I18n so it is a parallell system but it works, although not pretty and it is not a replacement to I18n but it has the important functionality of being able to easily add a locale and handle all translations in one form.

- Translation model with key:string
- In Translation model:

  translates :value
  globalize_accessors :locales => I18n.available_locales, :attributes => [:value]

In ApplicationHelper:

```
  def t2(key_str)
    key_stringified = key_str.to_s.gsub(":", "")
    t = Transl8er.find_by_key(key_stringified)
    if t.blank? 
      # Translation missing
      if t.is_a? String
        return_string = "Translation missing for #{key_str}"
      else
        return_string = key_str 
      end
    else
      begin
        return_string = t.value.strip
      rescue
        return_string = t.value
      end
    end
    return_string
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make an ActiveRecord object for the translation table, and then create read and write functions on that model.

Read function would pull all associated records then combine them into a single hash.

Write function would take your single hash input and split them into multiple records for writing/updating.

Comment: I get that in theory but how to make it work with the gem and make it in practise is a completely different thing though.